# Android Studio - Android SDK Missing and Connection Issues

Tags: windows-10, installation, android, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio at the moment, but get stuck at this error:

["Your Android SDK is missing, outdate or corrupted"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYcaD.png)

When opening the SDK Manager and going to the SDK Setup it shows the SDK as already being Installed, even though they don't exist, and shows the standard file path (which also does not exist, and is not created when I click Next.)

[Android SDK (Installed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvKfQ.png)

When I click continue I get the following message

["SDK is up to date
Tools Directory is missing"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaHzF.png)

The whole directory in Appdate does not exist however, so there's nothing to add the Tools directory to, either. I've already tried manually adding the SDK

[SDK Manually added to appdata/Android/SDK/tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T4Qo.png)

in the standard folder but then I just get these error messages:

["Target folder is neither empty nor does it contain an SDK installation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt4Er.png)

And if I try to continue it just shows

[Android SDK is up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJD8T.png)

but still does not work, or detect the SDK in the folder.

I'm guessing it can't download the SDK for the same reason I cannot check for updates, which just gives me a

[Connection Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx02h.png)

error message. I'm already running Android Studio as Admin, tried a fresh install, tried manually adding the SDK and tried updating with my firewall temporarily disabled, which just gives me the same error message. I've tried adding the path through Configure>Project Details>Project Structure but that just gets stuck on

["Checking Availability" 
"SDK does not contain any platforms"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLARd.png)

I'm using Comodo for internet security and am on Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same Problems you describe! I have not figured out why the SDK is not getting installed, but atleast i was able to come up with a Workaround.

**Install Unity!**
During the Installation process of Unity you have the opportunity to include Android compatibility and therefore to download the Android SDK. 
Make sure to select Android compatibility including SDK and wait for Unity to finish. Afterwards try reinstalling Android study, it should now start to download and install the SDK (i think These are just some remaining files Unity doesn't Need).

*(I tried installing Android Studio on my work Laptop and everything worked fine. The only difference between this and my home Setup is that i also got Unity installed on my Workstation.)*